# Are NP-Complete languages closed under any regular operations?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, closure-properties

I have tried looking online, but I couldn't find any definitive statements. It would make sense to me that Union and Intersection of two NPC languages would produce a language not necessarily in NPC. Is it also true that NPC languages are not closed under the complement, concatenation, and kleene star operations?

Comment: just a note: regular operations are union, concatenation and Kleene star and **not** intersection and complement

Comment: Why not intersection and complement? I haven't seen any formal definition of regular operations anywhere.

Comment: @Tushar Indeed: union, concatenation and Kleene star are regular operations, whereas union, intersection and complement are Boolean operations. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties).

Comment: @Tushar: Because these operations are used to build **regular** expressions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For all of the examples in this answer, I'm taking the alphabet to be $\{0,1\}$. Note that the languages $\emptyset$ and $\{0,1\}^*$ are definitely not **NP**-complete.

- The class of **NP**-complete languages is not closed under intersection.  For any **NP**-complete language $L$, let $L_0 = \{0w\mid w\in L\}$ and $L_1 = \{1w\mid w\in L\}$.  $L_0$ and $L_1$ are both **NP**-complete but $L_0\cap L_1 = \emptyset$.
- The class of **NP**-complete languages is not closed under union. Given the **NP**-complete languages $L_0$ and $L_1$ from the previous part, let $L'_0 = L_0 \cup \{1w\mid w\in \{0,1\}^*\}\cup\{\varepsilon\}$ and $L'_1 = L_1\cup \{0w\mid w\in \{0,1\}^*\}\cup\{\varepsilon\}$.  $L'_0$ and $L'_1$ are both **NP**-complete but $L'_0\cup L'_1 = \{0,1\}^*\!$.
- The class of **NP**-complete languages is not closed under concatenation. Consider the **NP**-complete languages $L'_0$ and $L'_1$ from the previous part.  Since both languages contain $\varepsilon$, we have $L'_0L'_1 \supseteq L'_0\cup L'_1 = \{0,1\}^*\!$.
- The class of **NP**-complete languages is not closed under Kleene star.  For any **NP**-complete language $L$, $L\cup \{0,1\}$ is **NP**-complete but $\big(L\cup \{0,1\}\big)^* = \{0,1\}^*\!$.
- If the  class of **NP**-complete problems is closed under complementation, then **NP** = **coNP**. Whether this is true or not is one of the major open problems in complexity theory.

Comment: Excluding the complement, aren't NP-complete languages closed under all of those? Or is that for P?

Comment: @Adjit Um. I proved that **NP** is closed under none of them.

Comment: For your specific language. But I guess I'm not seeing how `{0, 1}*` is not NP-complete. If you take, for instance, the intersection of 2 NP-complete languages shouldn't you get an NP-complete language, thereby making NP closed under intersection?

Comment: {0, 1}* and the empty language are regular, thus decidable in polynomial time and not NP-Complete. @DavidRicherby showed that there exist two NP-Complete languages the intersection of which is not NP-Complete. That is sufficient to prove NPC is not *closed* under intersection.

Comment: @weirdev No! $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ are not **NP**-complete because no other languages reduce to them. It's not enough to say that they're in **P** -- we don't know that languages in **P** can't be **NP**-complete.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Crap you are correct. The first sentence of my comment should have been what you wrote "∅ and Σ∗ are not NP-complete because no other languages reduce to them".

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the proofs for union, intersection, concatenation, and kleene star of NP languages, [here](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~srba/courses/tutorials-CC-10/t13-sol.pdf). Its seems like a similar argument could be made for NP-Complete languages.

For notation let

- $A$ be a oracle that decides a known NP-Complete problem like 3-SAT. See the definition of [turing reducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reducible)
- $L_1$ and $L_2$ are NP-Complete languages
- $M_1$ and $M_2$ are Turing machines that decide $L_1$ and $L_2$ using $A$.
- $L_3$ is $L_1 \cup L_2$
- $M_3$ is a turing machine that decides $L_3$

In the case of union from [1](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~srba/courses/tutorials-CC-10/t13-sol.pdf), we can create a new machine $M_3$ that decides $L_3$ by calling $M_1$ and $M_2$ as sub routines. In turn, each time $M_1$ or $M_2$ is called, $A$ is also called. So $M_3$ decides $L_3$ using $A$. By the argument from [1](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~srba/courses/tutorials-CC-10/t13-sol.pdf), the running time of $M_3$ is in P and since it uses $A$ as a subroutine, $L_3$ is NP-Complete. In other words, $L_3$ is NP-Complete for the same reason that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are NP-Complete.

The same argument can be made intersection and it looks like similar arguments could be made for concatenation, and kleene star.

In the case of compliment, it seems likely to be difficult to prove for the same reasons is difficult to [prove compliment in NP.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24261/is-the-class-np-closed-under-complement/24265#24265)

Comment: NP-completeness is defined in terms of many-one reductions, not oracle reductions. Further, the NP-complete languages are definitely not closed under union or intersection. If they're closed under complement, then NP=coNP, which is a major open question.

Comment: In Stephen Cook's 1971 paper[1] which **defines** NP-Completeness he uses a Query machine which is the same concept as an Oracle. You should also check out the link above on turing reducibility. 
[1] http://www.chell.co.uk/media/product/_master/1/files/cook_complexity_of_theorem_proving_procedures_19712.pdf

Comment: @joebloggs: I can see from your argument that union and intersection of two NP-Complete languages is NP. However, it still doesn't prove whether it is NP-complete. You have to reduce the union or intersection of two NP-complete decision problem to a NP-complete decision problem to show that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: You say that the NP-complete languages are definitely not closed under union or intersection. I am interested in looking at the proof for that. Do you have any references for that proof?

Comment: @joebloggs Sure but that definition isn't used any more. We don't even know if **NP** is closed under polytime Turing reductions. Karp's seminal paper uses many-one reductions.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it doesn't matter if "that argument is not used anymore" they are equivalent definitions.

Comment: @DavidRicherby does your argument not also "prove" that **P** is not closed under intersection, union, and kleene star?

Comment: @joebloggs As far as I'm aware, the two definitions of **NP**-completeness (via Cook and Karp reductions) are not known to be equivalent.

Comment: @joebloggs If you want to comment about my answer, please do so as a comment about my answer, not a comment about yours.

Comment: @joebloggs: Your argument works for NP-languages, but NOT for NP-complete languages. To prove that a language L is Np-complete, you need to provide a polynomial reduction from L to a known NP-complete language. As for David's answer, P is closed under intersection, because both empty language and universal language are in P (hence, they are in NP too), but they are not NP-complete. Hope that makes it clear!

Comment: @joebloggs Here's a difference between Cook and Karp reductions. Admittedly, it's rather trivial but it does show they're different. If **P=NP**, then every language in **P** is **NP**-complete under Cook reductions (just solve the problem in the reduction) but $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ are not **NP**-complete under Karp reductions (you can't map a "yes" instance of any language to a "yes" instance of the empty language because it has no "yes" instances).