# Are NP-complete sets formed from two other sets only if at least one is NP-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, np, np-intermediate

This question is somewhat of a converse to [a previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45410/are-non-trivial-sets-formed-by-set-operations-on-npc-sets-still-in-npc/45530#45530) on sets formed from set operations on NP-complete sets:

If the set resulting from the union, intersection, or Cartesian
product of two decidable sets $L_1$  and $L_2$ is NP-complete, is at
least one of $L_1, L_2$ necessarily NP-hard?  I know that they cannot
both be in P (assuming P != NP) since P is closed under these set operations.  I also
know that the conditions of "decidable" and "NP-hard" are necessary
since if we consider any NP-complete set $L$ and another set $B$ outside
of NP (whether just NP-hard or undecidable) then we can form two
new NP-hard sets not in NP whose intersection is NP-complete.  For
example: $L_1:= 01L \cup 11B$, and $L_2:= 01L \cup 00B$.  However,
I don't know how to proceed after that.

I'm thinking that the case of union might not be true since we can take a NP-complete set $A$ and perform the construction in Ladner's Theorem to get a set $B \in$ NPI which is a subset of $A$.  Then $B \cup (A \setminus B) =  A$ is the original NP-complete set.  However, I don't know if $A \setminus B$ is still in NPI or NP-hard.  I don't even know where to start for the case of intersection and Cartesian product.

Comment: A problem in P can be NP-complete if P=NP, which makes your claim "they cannot both be in P" false.

Comment: @Wojowu  Thank you, you are correct.  I just assumed that it was understood that this whole question is based on the premise that P != NP.  Otherwise it is meaningless/trivial since we would then have NPC = P.  I will edit the question.

Comment: @Ari, Actually $NPC\not = P$, even if $P=NP$.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden How is that possible? $NPC \subseteq NP$ so if P = NP then every problem in NP can be solved in polynomial time including problems in NPC.

Comment: @Ari The empty set and the set of all strings are in $NP$, but they're not $NP$-complete. You can't reduce anything to the empty set (or set of all strings) because it's always a no (resp. yes) instance.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of two non-NP-hard languages can be NP-hard.  Example: The solutions of any 3SAT instance are the set intersection of the solutions of a HORN-3SAT instance and an ANTIHORN-3SAT instance.  This is because a 3CNF clause must be either a Horn or anti-Horn clause and a 3SAT instance is the conjunction of such clauses.  3SAT is of course NP-complete; HORN-3SAT and ANTIHORN-3SAT are both in P.

Comment: I can't follow your example. The intersection of HORN-SAT and ANTIHORN-SAT is a pretty boring language that is definitely in P.

Comment: I agree that deciding whether a string is in the intersection of the two languages is in P.  But given arbitrary HORN-3SAT and ANTIHORN-3SAT instances over the same variables, finding strings within that intersection is NP-hard, and so must be the language.

Comment: HORN-3SAT can be defined in many ways. One way is to fix an encoding of HORN-3SAT instances – each string encodes some such instance – and then HORN-3SAT consists of the satisfiable instances. This encoding is likely different from the encoding you would use for ANTIHORN-3SAT, so it's not clear what the intersection language exactly is – definitely not SAT.

Comment: Another possibility is to define HORN-3SAT as the language of 3SAT instances which are (i) in Horn form, (ii) satisfiable. Now the intersection of HORN-3SAT and ANTIHORN-3SAT does make sense: it consists of all 3SAT instances which are (i) in both Horn and anti-Horn forms, (ii) satisfiable. This can only be *easier* than each of HORN-3SAT and ANTIHORN-3SAT.

Comment: A third, quite strange, possibility is to define HORN-3SAT as the language of 3SAT instances whose Horn part is satisfiable. Even under this definition we don't get 3SAT as the intersection of HORN-3SAT and ANTIHORN-3SAT, since we cannot enforce the satisfying assignments for both parts to be identical.

Comment: The third possibility is where I'm going with my answer.  Take a 3SAT instance and separate it into its Horn and anti-Horn parts.  Every clause goes into one pile or the other.  The satisfying assignments for the whole 3SAT instance are exactly the intersection of the satisfying assignments for the Horn parts alone and the satisfying assignments for the anti-Horn parts alone.

Comment: This is a very strange definition of language intersection, different from the one that was meant here. If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are languages (such as 3SAT), by their intersection we mean $L_1 \cap L_2$.

Comment: In fact, under this definition the intersection and union of two languages in P are always in P.

Comment: @KyleJones@Yuval I think there might be some confusion regarding instances vs. languages.  While every **instance** of 3SAT is certainly composed solely of Horn clauses and Anti-Horn clauses, it is **not** the case that the **language** $\mathsf{3SAT}$ equals $\mathsf{HORN3SAT}\cap\mathsf{ANTIHORN3SAT}$ or alternatively $\mathsf{HORN3SAT}\cup\mathsf{ANTIHORN3SAT}$ since these sets have instances each composed _solely_ of Horn clauses or Anti-Horn clauses whereas each instance of 3SAT can have a mixture of these two types of clauses..

Comment: What you have shown is that, if you're given an oracle that lists solutions of HORN3SAT instances and an oracle that lists solutions of ANTIHORN3SAT instances, you can solve 3SAT. That's a nice observation but it doesn't answer the question. The question is asking, essentially, if there can be languages (sets of strings) $L_1$ and $L_2$ such that $L_1\cap L_2$ is exactly the set of strings coding satisfiable 3SAT instances.